# Google Calendar API - 403 - "This service is not available from your country"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an application that utilizes the Google Calendar API. It was working until yesterday when I started receiving the following response. It seems as if Google is misinterpreting the location of the IP address of my VPS server. When I run the application from a local computer, it runs as expected.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest returned "This service is not available from your country"**

Comment: Where is your server located?

Comment: I'm using DigitalOcean and this instance is located in their NYC2 datacenter.

Comment: To workaround the problem I took a snapshot of my server and spun up a new instance in their San Francisco datacenter with a new IP address.  Now with the new IP address the API calls are working again.